# RxCocoa: Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)'

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I use RxCocoa, I have code like this,

```
func debug(){
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)


        tap.rx.event.bind { (event) in

            if self.phone.text == Phone.one{
                self.phone.text = Phone.two
            }
            else{
                self.phone.text = Phone.one
            }
            self.verification.text = ""
        }.disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

    }
```

I want to do some encapsulation, turn the above to this:

```
func debug( _ event: (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void){


        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.rx.event.bind(to: event).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

    }
```

Xcode reports:

> Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)'

I try

```
 func debug( _ event: @escaping (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void){
```

Xcode reports:

```
 Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: @escaping (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)'
```

---

**What matters?  Rx name space?**

When I type `event`in the former, Xcode tips `event` is `UITapGestureRecognizer`

[image: 111]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `bind(onNext: @escaping (E) -> Void)` is what you look for, rather than `bind<O: ObserverType>(to observer: O)`.

Compare implementations:

```swift
public func bind<O: ObserverType>(to observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E {
    return self.subscribe(observer)
}

public func bind(onNext: @escaping (E) -> Void) -> Disposable {
    return subscribe(onNext: onNext, onError: { error in
        rxFatalErrorInDebug("Binding error: \(error)")
    })
}
```